# Probability question and probability functions

Tags: probability

Given a probability function $p_x(n) = \frac{c}{4^n}$ with ($c$ being a constant) with a sample space of  $X: n= 1,2,\dots$

The question asks to calculate the probability of $P(X \ge 2)$, answer is actual number not something multiplied by c.

I have been given this question , and sorry for the horrible translation, im learning a course in probability and statistics in a different language, the question was bothering me for a while, even if i try to remove the constant and work from there dont know why im still stuck at this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability function needs to be normalized to sum to 1 so
$$1 = \sum p(n) = c \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n = \frac{c}{3}.$$
This implies that $c = 3$. We want to calculate the probability that $X \ge 2$, I assume this means
$$P(X\ge 2) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{c}{4^n} = c \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{4}.$$